# Where is the documentation on res.on('end'

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Just cant find it!  looking for documentation on the following on error, data, and end

```
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     https.get(setUrl(substr), (res) => {
       let data = ''
       res.on('data', (d) => {
         data += d
       });
       res.on('end', () => resolve(data));
     }).on('error', reject);
  });
```

Comment: It's probably part of the documentation for `https.get()`. You don't tell us what kind of object `https` is, so it's hard to say more without a lot of guessing.

Comment: @TedHopp - `https` is the [https module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) built into node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the doc for [`https.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback), it says to go look at the doc for [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) for the callback parameters.

There it says:

> The callback is invoked with a single argument that is an instance of `http.IncomingMessage`.

And, if you then go look at the doc for [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), you find that:

> It implements the [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) interface, as well as the following additional events, methods, and properties.

In [that doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), you will find a description of the [`data`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) and [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) events.

The `https.get()` itself returns an [`http.ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) object and in the doc for [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) which `https.get()` is derived from, it explains:

> If any error is encountered during the request (be that with DNS resolution, TCP level errors, or actual HTTP parse errors) an 'error' event is emitted on the returned request object. As with all 'error' events, if no listeners are registered the error will be thrown.

---

Yes, it is work to follow all this.  This is one of the aspects of object oriented design with lots of derived and common objects.  You have to find the object being used or perhaps even the base object and then go look in its doc for find out how to use it.